# cocos2d custom dialog box with yes/no choices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uialertview

As of now, I can only do:

```
`UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
 [dialog setDelegate:self];
 [dialog setTitle:@"New Game"];
 [dialog setMessage:@"Are you sure you want to start a new game? This will overwrite your current game."];
 [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
 [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"No"];
 [dialog show];
 [dialog release];

...

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex==0) {
        gametype = 1;
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionCrossFade transitionWithDuration:1 scene:[GameScene node]]];
    }
}
`
```

The bad thing is that the dialog box really does not mix in with the whole theme of the application.

Is there a way I can customize or create a dialogue box that appears?

I've heard that customizing UIAlertView has been very controversial to the point of being rejected form the app store. I don't think I should go with this method. Do you have any suggestions/code I can use?

PS: I have a dialogue box image and yes/no buttons already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a dialog box and YES/NO buttons, then I would just add the dialog box the the layer a sprite with the YES/NO buttons overlaid as CCMenuItemImage(s).  Then you can have the no button just hide the visibility of the menu and the dialog box and the yes button replace the scene.

```
dialogBox = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"dialogBox.png"];
CCMenuItemImage *yesButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"yes.png" selectedImage:@"yes.png" target:self selector:@selector(yesSelector)]
CCMenuItemImage *noButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"no.png" selectedImage:@"no.png" target:self selector:@selector(noSelector)]
```

Then in your noSelector method you can just hide the dialog box and in your yesSelector just replace the scene.

Comment: DO you mean just add it as a layer? Hmm, I haven't tried that before... How do I do so?

Comment: @kazuo check the edits to get started...You can add it as a layer or as a sprite, it would probably be easier for you to just add the dialog box as a sprite.

Comment: A follow-up question: in doing that, would the rest of the stuff behind the dialog box still be clickable? I would like everything else blacked out and disabled so there is full focus on the box. :)

Comment: @kazuo If you wanted that then it may be best to just add a layer.  You could just add a CCLayerColor that's grey and with a bit of opacity.  I'm assuming you're using menu items for the buttons so you could just set there touchEnabled property to be no like [mainMenu setIsTouchEnabled:NO];